# How can this user code input procedure be exploited?

Tags: php

I'm trying to come up with a way that a user can input code fragments that will be able to run both server-side and client-side. In an ideal world, I'd have a LUA interpreter or a Javascript engine on the server which I could call out to, but I don't see either of those as an easy solution (to set up on my dev machine OR find a host that will do it).

I've got an idea of allowing the user to write a code snippet to run in Javascript, then translate it to be used in PHP.

The usage is for the user to write the internals of a function call which does various things. A (very) simple example would be to give the user a function that takes the parameter 'amount', and they could write a string like `amount * 1.05` (which then translates to `function(amount) { return amount * 1.05; }` in Javascript, or `function($amount) { return $amount * 1.05; }` in PHP. A more complicated example would be `(speed < 9) ? Math.pow(speed, (10 / 3)) : Math.pow(speed, (10 / 3) + (-0.5 * Math.log(10 - speed) / Math.log(10)))`. For protection in the PHP side, only recognized variable names (the function parameters, such as amount or speed in the two prior examples) have a $ placed on them, and certain known Javascript library calls or functions like Math are/will be translated (in the case of Math, all of the Javascript functions are directly compatible with PHP, so we just strip "Math."). The PHP code would then be run through something like `$func = eval(Pseudocode::generatePhpCode($code));` to get the server-side function.

My question is - despite my attempts to LIMIT what can be run, could this be exploited somehow? What improvements can I make?

```
static function generatePhpCode($pseudocode, $parameterList)
{
    // Make a list of things that are not allowed in the "pseudocode"
    $illegal = ['$', '@', '->', '::', '`', 'exec', 'eval', 'system', 'passthru', 'popen', 'pclose', 'fopen', 'fclose', 'proc_', 'select', 'shell', 'sql', 'ini', 'echo'];
    foreach ($illegal as $string) {
        if (strpos($pseudocode, $string) !== false) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Attempted to pass illegal pseudocode function.');
        }
    }

    $paramList = '';
    foreach ($parameterList as $param) {
        $pseudocode = str_replace(['Math.', $param], ['', '$' . $param], $pseudocode);

        $paramList .= ',$' . $param;
    }

    return
        'function (' . ltrim($paramList, ',') . ') {' . PHP_EOL .
        '    return ' . $pseudocode . ';' . PHP_EOL .
        '};';
}
```

Comment: A few tips: Never underestimate someone's ability to abuse your code. Trying to blacklist things that can't be run means you have to have fairly complete knowledge of the PHP API. I'd recommend whitelisting the things that can be run instead. Also, even using only 'safe' functions, it would be fairly trivial to write an infinite loop that will *at best* chew up a lot of resources on your server and make it vulnerable to DDoS attacks.

Comment: After some of the readings that I have seen, about the only computing device that can not be exploited is one that is not turned on.  Opening up any kind of a mechanism to allow someone any kind of a free form data entry seems to be something that can be exploited just take a look at SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

Comment: There may be ways to mangle/obfuscate the input code such that it passes your black list.

Comment: @JosdeJong - I thought about that, but I couldn't find any way to do it with in a single statement ('return' is prepended to the user input) and without direct access to any classes. I also disabled access to 'new' after the above post.

Comment: @Steve I will check that out. Looks promising, but what kind of overhead is involved?